# What to look for in an Inertial Measurement Unit?

Tags: accelerometer, gyroscope

I'm trying to implement an inertial measurement unit (IMU) in a project of mine, but I don't have much experience in this field. There's some terminology that I don't understand. For example, what does **In-Run Bias stability, Random Walk, and bias repeatability** mean. I have googled these terms, but still don't have an understand of them. For my application, I need to measure linear acceleration, velocity, and position (I am aware of the drift issue) and roll pitch and yaw of a vehicle.

Comment: Bias refers to the gyro, which has the most problems with accuracy because of bias and drift. Being an engineering student, you should first find out what the requirements are. A good engineer knows how to design using requirements. How much velocity or position error can the design tolerate and still preform? How much rate error is acceptable?

Comment: Your tags that you made for this question "acceleratometer" and "gyroscope" suggest that you know the tools you need for measurement. Many of these ICs contain places where you can wire up an I2C (or SPI if you need a faster interface) bus to. These datasheets for these ICs will tell you how to assign an address as well as reading and writing information to the IC via its status registers.